# Kivy widgets delay on setting state/value on start

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have various widgets that I want to resume where they left off when the program is closed (Slider at 50 when the program is closed, will still be at 50 when the program is reopened).

I achieve this by storing the state or value of the widget in a file every time it changes, and then when the app is opened the file is read and stored in a list.  All of the widgets have a line which sets their state/value based on the data in that list.

The issue is that if the program is run for the first time, no file exists to read the values out of, so one is created and then proceed like normal, but the kivy widgets have already tried to assign the values/states before the information is there.

What I need to make this work is a way to delay the widgets from assigning their state/value without having a custom class for every widget, as that is a problem on another question I have asked unrelated to this.

```
Slider:
    id: red_slider
    size_hint: .13, 1
    min: 0
    max: 255
    step: 1
    value: app.quicksave_boot[0]
    cursor_image: 'bin/img/red_s.png'
    cursor_size: (dp(30), dp(8))
    orientation: 'vertical'
    on_touch_move: root.hex_update(self, green_slider, blue_slider, hex_code_input)
    on_touch_up: root.quicksave(self, 'RS')
```

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Slider:
    id: red_slider
    on_kv_post: self.value = app.stored_data.get('Quicksave')['RS']
    size_hint: .13, 1
    min: 0
    max: 255
    step: 1
    cursor_image: 'bin/img/red_s.png'
    cursor_size: (dp(30), dp(8))
    orientation: 'vertical'
    on_touch_move: root.hex_update(self, green_slider, blue_slider, hex_code_input)
    on_touch_up: root.quicksave(self, 'RS')
```

Fired after all the kv rules associated with the widget and all other widgets that are in any of those rules have had all their kv rules applied. base_widget is the base-most widget whose instantiation triggered the kv rules (i.e. the widget instantiated from Python, e.g. MyWidget()).

Credit to: **kuzeyron#3623** and **NOTSLEEP#1554** for the heavy lifting in finding a solution to this problem